# Trigger a form submit using hidden input type=file

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a button which on click calls the input tag with "type=file"

**javascript code:**

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td  >
     <button type="button" style="width:207px" onclick="ClickMe()">Click</button>

    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

  <form action="/uploadExcelservlet" name="uploadExcelFile" method="POST"            enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <input type="file" class="Hello" name ="Hello">
  </form>
```

When Click is selected. I try calling "Hello" to open a browse window.

User selects a file. How do I retrieve the filename here, so I can post it to server and  retrieve file in the server.

**js file:**

```
function ClickMe()
{
var frm = document.Hello;
$(function() {
     $(".Hello").click();
          $("[name='Hello']").change(function () {
              alert('here');
              if($(this).val()!=""){
                  frm.submit();
              }
           });
    })
}
```

Comment: You code works: http://jsfiddle.net/WJrhp/ are you wanting to then post it with ajax? Otherwise, it should work as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your js code to

```
  $(function () {
    $("[name='Hello']").change(function () {
      alert($(this).val());
      if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $("form").submit();
      }
    });
  })

  function ClickMe() {
    $(".Hello").click();
  }
```

Check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/WJrhp/2/)